# Init new instance the first time a static method is called on a class

Tags: typescript

I'd like to initialize a new instance of a class the first time a static method is called on it. I'm not sure this is possible the way I want to do it.

For example, I'd like these 2 apis to work in producing a new instance with the desired values:

```js
Route.path('/login').middleware('guest')
Route.middleware('auth').path('/dashboard')
```

I have looked into typescript's static blocks and thought it would be possible like this:

```js
class Route {
    static config: {
        path?: string,
        middleware?: string,
    }

    static {
        console.log('called static')
        this.config = {}
    }

    static path(path: string) {
        this.config.path = path
        return this
    }

    static middleware(middleware: string) {
        this.config.middleware = middleware
        return this
    }
}
```

However the `config` values are the same when I log the result:

```js
console.log([
    Route.path('/login').middleware('guest').config,
    Route.middleware('auth').path('/dashboard').config,
])
```

```json
[
  {
    path: "/dashboard",
    middleware: "auth",
  }, {
    path: "/dashboard",
    middleware: "auth",
  }
]
```

And the `called static` log only shows up in the console once.

Is it possible to get this to work without using the `new` keyword and converting all of the methods to non-static?